# How to efficiently remove non-words characters from string in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a string as follows:

> Hi there. My zip code is 9876543. Also my email-Id is
>   myname@domain.com.

I want to clean this string by removing non-words characters from it like `".", "@", numbers, ...`

How to achieve it in Scala? Is there a built in function in Scala where I just give a list of characters which I don't want and it will filter the string automatically?

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for. print(str.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z])", ""))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ Thanks to Dima for point out that `*` is not needed when using `replaceAll` ]

The simple solution is

```
 str.replaceAll("\\W", "")
```

This replaces all occurrences of a regular expression with another string. The regular expression for a word character is `\w` and a non-word character is `\W`, so this replaces all non-word characters with nothing.

If you want a more complex test then look at any introduction to regular expressions to see how to do this.

#### Edit

If you are using accented characters or characters from other alphabets, use the Unicode expressions. For example, to retain all Unicode alphabetic characters, use this:

```
 str.replaceAll("\\P{L}", "")
```

This will avoid losing the first e in créche, for example.

Comment: This is the correct answer, no idea who downvoted it. 
One correction though: you don't need the `*` here: it is redundant, and makes the whole thing more confusing than it needs to be. It also hurts the performance someone (albeit, probably, not enough to be noticeable in any practical situation).

Comment: Minor note, but I'd suggest using triple-quoted strings for regular expressions to avoid doubling backslashes.

Comment: And what if I want to keep only english letters and no numbers? Is there a standard regex exists in Scala like the "W+".? Thanks.

Comment: `"[\\W\\d]"` or, as mentioned in the comments, `"""[\W\d]"""`

Comment: `[\W\d]` will also keep underscores (those are also "word characters". If you want only letters, do `[^A-z]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to leave letters and spaces and filter everything else, in Scala one can do it as simple as:

```
"Hi there. My zip code is 9876543. Also my email-Id is myname@domain.com."
  .filter(c => c.isLetter || c.isWhitespace)
// > res: String = "Hi there My zip code is  Also my emailId is mynamedomaincom"
```

If you logic is more complex then I assumed, go for regular expression.